# Location and visibility of the SharePoint users group

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created a group of users in the SharePoint subsite, i.e. pressed `Create Group` button on a ribbon of this particular subsite `Permissions` page. Nevertheless I see this group in the list of groups in my parent site.

Does this mean that all SharePoint groups are stored on the site collection level? Meaning that all groups are relevant to any site in the collection?

If this is so, what were the reasons for this design?

Comment: Yes, you can access all groups from the main site. And I guess the reason is to give you the ability to use any group in any website under your collection.

Comment: Do you mean "you can access any group from any site in the collection"? Can you, please, post it as an answer that I will be able to accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can access all groups from the main site and **any** website in the collection. And I guess the reason is to give you the ability to use any group in any website under your collection.